# App Store: Remove iPhone 3G compatibility from my app (because VoiceOver is required)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voiceover

My app requires VoiceOver (it's specially designed for visually impaired people) which is only available for iPhone 3GS and later.

Is there a possibility to declare that my app requires an iPhone 3GS or later?

My temporary "solution" is to require iOS 4.3 or later (iOS 4.3 is not available for iPhone 3G devices). But to require that doesn't feel right.

Comment: Probably too late, but you should file a bug asking for it to be put in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities as well.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like as good a method as any. Another way would be to require armv7 architecture, but I was advised against that by Apple when I asked unless my app actually did use armv7.